# basic android file system

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, file-system, file-management

I have a samsung galaxy 8, new to android from iphone 7. Since this system is new to me I wanted to get a rundown on the internal/sd storage files, where system files are stored, how to find apps and where they are stored. Basically I want to manage some files but I don't know the structure on the android system. Example: I want to store some lesser used icon packs to the external storage to free up some space. I don't know where to move them to, and what rules there may be for this. 
I also have alot of photo files which I want to store and use from the sd card.
If someone can please direct me to an article that would be really helpful.

Comment: Some starting points at our site: [Android Folder Hierarchy](/q/46926/16575) / [Where Android apps store data?](/q/47924/16575). Also worth checking: our tag-wikis often contain some basic background and link to most relevant answered questions, see e.g. the one for [internal-storage](/tags/internal-storage/info).

Answer (score -1):

You can download Es File Explorer App, click [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) to download it from Google Play Store. It makes easy to manage your files in Internal/External Storage, using this you can easily move your photos from Internal to External storage.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: ES once was a good one, now it comes with too much adware attached. For replacements, there's my app listing of [file managers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman); depending on your background, good candidates include *Total Commander* / *Ghost Commander* / *Astro* or *Amaze* – and I'd currently rather go for the latter: it's open source, and includes an app manager.

Comment: @Izzy I am using it for years and I have not faced any issue with it yet, but I will look the suggestions you mentioned.

Comment: Well, ES added at least AdMob and MoPub, then Appsflyer, Avocarrot and Taboola – all for ads. Additionally, the app is linked to Firebase (probably for analytics). Doesn't feel good privacy-wise. Amaze has none of that (umm, exact for Firebase if you install it from Playstore – luckily it's also available at F-Droid) while covering almost everything ES does.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for improving my knowledge, this was really helpful.

Comment: Always glad to help! As a last note: some of the "more dangerous modules" (also see my article [What’s it all about those modules apps contain?](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/app-modules-1)) are pointed out by "monitor icons" in my app lists, others can be seen when following the AppBrain links from there.

Comment: I fail to see how the answer addresses a good part of the question; namely, `where are [apps] stored`, `where system files are stored`, `what rules there may be [for moving files]`. Sorry, but -1.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I already have that app, thats why I need more information on the file system specific to android.